# how to redirect_to and return a 200 status code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that pings stripe with a new credit card when the user fills out the form. It then redirects back to the homepage when its' done. However, stripe says i'm returning a 503 (i think that's the code) instead of a 200. I'm doing a regular redirect_to :root. How do I make sure to also return a 200 code?

Comment: Also are you sure you're not getting a StripeException?

Comment: a normal redirect doesn't return a 503 error. I think we need some more context - why does stripe care what you're returning in your browser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't.

The rails method

```
redirect_to some_path
```

works by sending to the browser an HTTP response with a [302 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) and an URL destination (as an HTTP response header).
Once the browser receives the response, it will automatically fire a new HTTP request to the new URL.

The redirection **does not** happen in Rails. A lot of people think that `redirect_to` is a way to jump from a controller's action to another, but it actually just asks the browser to send another request.

Now, browsers know how to handle this kind of response because `302` is an HTTP status code. That's its meaning. You **can** change the status code of a `redirect_to` to `200`, but that will break the redirection.

Answer (score -4):

redirect_to :root, status: :ok

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I get that, I was under the impression he didn't know how to do so.  He did say "How do I make sure to also return a 200 code?".