# Rails 6 Minitest file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to create a test for a file upload in Rails 6 with Minitest.
I have seen several post on Stack Overflow, about this issue, but I still has not abe to get it to work.
When testing the upload manually works has expected. But I would like to build a test to it.
I am new to testing!

### My Routes

```
post "upload_validation", to: "products#upload_validation"
```

### My Controller

```
def upload_validation
    body = file_format_validation
    if body.present?
      request = RestClient.post(api_v1_products_url, body.to_json, set_http_headers({ content_type: :json, accept: :json }))

      json_response = JSON.parse(request.body)

      flash[:notice] = "Uploaded: #{json_response['products_uploaded']} | Saved: #{json_response['products_saved']}"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "Invalid file"
    end
  end

private

  def file_format_validation
    if params.key?(:file) && params[:file].content_type == "application/json"
      uploaded_file = params[:file]
      serialized_products = uploaded_file.tempfile.read
      JSON.parse(serialized_products)
    end
  end

  def set_http_headers(args = {})
    headers = {
      x_user_email: current_user.email,
      x_user_token: current_user.reload.authentication_token
    }
    if args.empty?
      headers
    else
      headers.merge(args)
    end
  end
```

### My View

```
<%= form_with url: upload_validation_path,local: false, multipart: true do |form| %>
      <%= form.file_field :file, accept: 'application/json', required: true %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Uplaod', class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

### My Test

In my `test/system/products_test.rb` I have the following code. Bu when I run the test

```
class ProductsTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase   
  test "upload file" do

    file_path = "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/products-test.json"
    json_file = fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/products-test.json",'application/json')
    post upload_validation_path,
      params: { file: json_file },
      headers: {
      content_type: "application/json"
    }
    assert_response 201
  end
end
```

When I run the test I get

```
Error:
ProductsTest#test_upload_file:
DRb::DRbRemoteError: undefined method `post' for #<ProductsTest:0x00007f9b67ac99a0> (NoMethodError)
    test/system/products_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:ProductsTest>'
```

If I use post upload_validation_url, I get

```
Error:
ProductsTest#test_upload_file:
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
    test/system/products_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:ProductsTest>'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[ApplicationSystemTestCase](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/SystemTestCase.html) seems to be wrong here.

Use [ActionController::TestCase](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html) instead.

Try `class ProductsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase` in a file called `products_controller_test.rb` in `test/controllers/products_controller`.

Comment: Thank you. It has (almost worked). The test now runs, but fails. It seems I need to isgin a user.

`Failure:
ProductsControllerTest#test_upload_file [/Users/jmschp/code/coodesh-ruby-on-rails-20200810/test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:12]:
Expected response to be a <201: Created>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>
Response body: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>.
Expected: 201
  Actual: 302`

Comment: This is what you application is doing, it redirects to the sign_in - regarding the 302 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623656/how-to-redirect-to-and-return-a-200-status-code) -  you should use `assert_redirected_to root_path`. If you render your json response, you could use what you have.