# How to handle unauthorized accesses gracefully in backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I have a Ruby on Rails application which redirects users to the start or login page if they end up at a resource they are not authorized for.
For that, it redirects through a 302 Found.

This does not feel right to me, as for example a successful creation of a resource via POST also returns a 302, with the only difference being that it redirects to the created resource.

On the other hand, it does not seem possible to [redirect a user without returning a 30X status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623656/how-to-redirect-to-and-return-a-200-status-code) (401/403 in this case).
Am I missing something here, or am I already doing it correctly and this is just the way to go?

Comment: 302 is actually the wrong response code for creating a resource. It should be `201 - CREATED` which also causes a redirect even though its not one of the 3XX status codes. The reason its used is that people are to lazy/ignorant to use `redirect_to @thing, status: :created`  (or use the responders gem) and write tests that test that the controller sends the right response code.

Comment: that is a very good tip, I am writing such tests now that is why I asked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'd say that it depends of the context, for an API I'd go for you way, if the user is trying to reach an endpoint without authentication or without enough permissions, I'd return a 401 or 403 respectively.

But for a web application without a separated frontend app, you've no choice to tell to the browser where it has to go next and the only way of doing this is to use redirections (that are only 3xx HTTP codes => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages).